# Bootsrap Affix not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, affix

I have added the library for Bootstrap and data-spy attribute where I want to make the div fix when I scroll the page down. But it doesn't work, I have almost tried everything, but not able to figure out the problem.
Is is something like the data-spy attribute doesn't work on class = "row" ?
Here's my code for HTML.

```
<div class="row">
           <h4> HEADING </h4>
           <h5>
            <div class="row" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="10">
            dsds
                Date : <input type="date" name="graph_date" id="graph_date">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="graph-hourly">
                    <div class="loader" id="chart_loader">
                        <p>Loading...</p>
                    </div>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
                    <div id="chart_hourly"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

and some css :

```
.affix {
  top : 0;
  width: 80%;
}
```

after searching for some solutions, I've added this also,

```
.affix-top {
  width: 100%;
}

.affix-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;  
}
```

but this solution also dosen't worked for me.

Comment: what do you mean by `lock` ? you mean sticky div ?

Comment: to fix the div basically

Comment: I don't understand your question at all I checked your code and where's the problem or what do you need by saying `lock` ? please provide more information

Comment: okay, Basically, I want my particular <div> to remain static ( which contains the date input type) when I scroll the page. This can be related to the same concept as -  'fix the navbar when we scroll the web page', but here it's not the navbar, it's the <div> element, which I want to remain when I scroll the web page.

Comment: what I understand is when user scroll down the `div` tag still in same place which called `sticky` if that I think I can help you

Comment: Maybe you can check this out, the change only is, I want my <div> instead of navbar in the following example: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy_affix&stacked=h)

Comment: I don't know the exact term for affix. if that's called `sticky` then I might've learned a new word, anyway can you help in this context?

Comment: yes I type the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all delete `top:0;` from affix class because it will make a issue for you.

now you have two methods pick a one :

## 1

adding `data-spy="affix"` which is works fine for me

## 2

same result ass `data-spy` but you will need some styling after you complete your page

by adding a `position` Property for `input` tag

as ex. :
CSS:

```
sticky{
position:fixed;
}
```

and HTML :

```
<input type="date" name="graph_date" class="sticky" id="graph_date">
```

## Update 1

this Jquery code can detect a scroll event so when user scroll down it will make the `div` tag sticky or "affix"

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var aTop = "100";
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= aTop) {
     $('#affix-this').css( "position", "fixed" );
     $('#affix-this').css( "top", "0" );
     $('#affix-this').css( "width", "100%" );
    }
  });
});
```

change the `aTop` variable with the height you want (in pixel) so when the user scroll down 100px the div become sticky

a [JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/xhg9nmhe/1/)

## Update 1.1

a bit smarter Jquery code do the same but get the height automatically from a another element this can be good if you format your page  to something similar to this

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var aTop = $('id').height();
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= aTop) {
     $('#affix-this').css( "position", "fixed" );
     $('#affix-this').css( "top", "0" );
     $('#affix-this').css( "width", "100%" );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I've tried the 1st solution, didn't worked for me. The second one did work, but it gets hide whenever some text is encounter.ed the date input gets hidden.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6wxchkkk/ , where's the problem ? you can add your full code on jsfiddle and I will check where's the problem

Comment: here's the link, my code does not work here. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dbxaf8jb/)

Comment: @YashJain see the update 1 , I think it solve the problem right ?

Comment: @YashJain pick what you need : update 1 or update 1.1 if it solve the problem accept the answer to move the question to answered section to help other users

Comment: can I know why this is didn't work with you ? i test it on JSFIDDLE .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is in your case. I copied and pasted your code into a jsfiddle with the bootstrap library and the affix class did work. Though, it worked badly because it affixed the row right when you started scrolling.

Looks like Bootstrap doesn't have a way to set the offset to the current position of the element so I added the following javascript to make it work.

```
$('#affix-this').affix({
    offset: {
      top: $('#affix-this').offset().top
    }
 })
```

(`#affix-this` should be changed to the id of the row you want to affix.)

Note the `$('#affix-this').offset().top`. This makes sure the element gets affixed right when you reach the element's current position.

Second, I removed the html attributes that you had for the affixing.

```
<div class="row">
    <h4> HEADING </h4>
    <div class="row" id="affix-this">
        dsds Date :
        <input type="date" name="graph_date" id="graph_date">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="graph-hourly">
      <div class="loader" id="chart_loader">
        <p>Loading...</p>
      </div>
      <div id="chart_hourly"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the `affix-this` id was added to the row that you want to affix.

Here is a working JSFiddle with these changes so you can see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/heraldo/6s4u26m3/4/

Comment: why this is also not working for me :( is there some issue for bootstrap files / Jquery files?

Comment: Yes, if this is not working, there's a problem with your setup. Make sure everything is included and loading properly. Check the console, are there any errors? The JSFiddle that I linked to works as it should, it has all of the bootstraps files correctly included.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element to which you're adding `data-spy="affix` has been created in the DOM before your Bootstrap scripts load. I ran into an issue where I was adding `data-spy="affix"` in my HTML, but it was wrapped up in a section that wasn't rendering, thanks to `data-ng-if`. My HTML was created after my Bootstrap had loaded, so the `<div>` I wanted to stick to the top of the screen never stayed in a fixed position. If you can, use `data-ng-show`, or something that merely hides HTML, rather than prevents it from being created on page load.